# Jackrabbit Running Queries against UUID

Tags: lucene, xpath, jackrabbit, jcr, jsr170

I am using Jackrabbit and I am trying to query for an existing node which has a UUID.
My code is shown below.  The problem is that UUID for referenceNode is of the form "'90be246a-a17c-445e-a5ad-81b064de0bee'" and it seems that the XPATH engine used in Jackrabbit (Lucene) has problems dealing with hyphens.

If I run query2, everything is fine and referenceNode is printed.
If I run query1 (with the UUID) inside Eclipse, nothing is returned.
HOWEVER, if I run query1 inside Jackrabbit Viewer, the query runs fine.

It seems like I have to escape the hyphens in my queryString but I tried adding double-backslashes and I get the same result.  What is the proper way to run queries against UUID's?

```
  // Set up Nodes
  rootNode = session.getRootNode();

  Node referenceNode = rootNode.addNode("referenceNode");
  Node referencingNode = rootNode.addNode("referencingNode");

  referenceNode.addMixin("mix:referenceable");
  referencingNode.setProperty("pointer", new ReferenceValue(referenceNode));

  // Query
  String uuid = referenceNode.getUUID();
  QueryManager qm = ws.getQueryManager();

  String queryString1 = "//*[@jcr:uuid='"+uuid+"']";
  String queryString2 = "//referenceNode";

  Query q = qm.createQuery(queryString1, Query.XPATH);

  QueryResult result = q.execute();

  NodeIterator it = result.getNodes();

  while(it.hasNext()) {
   Node node = it.nextNode();
   System.out.println( node.getName());
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that the node is not saved yet. As written in the [search documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Search), "Node names and property values are indexed as soon as the data is saved or as soon as the transaction is committed."

In this case, I guess you could use `Session.getNodeByIdentifier(String id)` instead of using a query. It should be much faster as well.

Comment: Thank you.  I added a simple session.save() after the setup and before the query and it worked.